# DotNetBrowser: How to use multiple IEngine?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, dotnetbrowser

I'm having trouble using multiple DotNetBrowser IEngine instances at once.

Whenever I try to use more than one at a time, they conflict, even though I have already defined different folders for each one.

Follow the code I'm using.

```
public void initializeBrowser(string guid)
    {
        string contextDirectory = Application.StartupPath + @"\cache\" + guid;
        string pathProxy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathProxy"];
        BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView()
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };
        engine = EngineFactory.Create(new EngineOptions.Builder
        {
            UserDataDirectory = contextDirectory,
            SandboxDisabled = true,
            RenderingMode = RenderingMode.OffScreen,
        }.Build());

        browserView.InitializeFrom(browser);
        browser = engine.CreateBrowser();
        browser.Navigation.FrameLoadFinished += delegate (object sender, FrameLoadFinishedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine($"FrameLoadFinished: URL = {e.ValidatedUrl},"
                                  + $" IsMainFrame = {e.Frame.IsMain}");
            
        };

    }
```